# how to take two input simultaneously in lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to add two numbers that are to be entered by the user in Lisp.  How can I do that?  I used the `read` command twice but it shows an error.

Comment: We cannot help you if you show neither code nor error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend parsing numbers from user input with the `parse-number` library.  Using `read` instead gives the user direct access to the Lisp reader, which you do not want.

Something like this should work:

```
(defun prompt-number (prompt &optional (prompt-stream *standard-output*)
                                       (read-stream *standard-input*))
  (format prompt-stream "~a: " prompt)
  (parse-number:parse-number (read-line read-stream)))
```

Comment: As long as you're only dealing with integers, `parse-integer` is quite handy, too.